# CFHTTP - strange results with passing cookies with the request

Tags: http, cookies, coldfusion

I am using cfhttp to login to a site, then want to send a second request to access data that requires login.

The first http request passes login details and logs in fine, I then get the cookies returned from the login and pass those into the second request .. `<cfparam type='cookie'` ...

The second request is giving a  not logged in response.

When I compare the value of the main session cookie I passed in, with the value of that cookie in the request header, it has changed.  Even if I manually copy and paste the actual value straight into the `<cfparam` value, when I check the Header of the request it is different.

An example of the actual value of the `_user_session` cookie is:

> BAh7CSIVdXNlcl9jcmVkZW50aWFscyIBgDNhNTJjZmU4YmZhZTA3NzYzNWY1MGViZmFiNDkyMmQ3MjFkODliZDNlMWFkYTI0MmY2YWYzZmMxMzhkZjE4NjNkZGRkN2VkNjljYTlmYTNjMjE1MjA3MzhmZmU5ZDY1NTYwMmM5MmRhNTkzOGRmZDY5NjE0OTU0Njk4OGI0ZTZlIg9zZXNzaW9uX2lkIiUzYzkxYTc1MGM3NGVkM2U0YTNlMzQyY2Y3MzAzZDY1ZCIYdXNlcl9jcmVkZW50aWFsc19pZGkCYgU6DnJldHVybl90bzA%3D--fd91306fe11f1f1a56a85b2c3f06be6e83f06ec5

But when I check the value of the `_user_session` cookie in the request header it is:

> BAh7ByIOcmV0dXJuX3RvIi8vZXh0cmFuZXQvcHJvcGVydGllcy8xMzI2L3Jlc2VydmF0aW9ucy5jc3YiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQiJTNmZTE2ZmIyOWNkNDk3MGRmZmZmYTY3ZDVhYzg1ZDRh--fb154a0e79a477e52dee3da1d5f62c2e456e567b

The first four digits are the same, (BAh7), but then the rest is a lot shorter and.. well.. just different..

Am I missing something here?  Can anyone explain what might be happening?

............................
............................

Thanks guys.. just want to be carefull posting actual code as it contains addresses and passwords and the like, but essentially this is what I have got it down to.. I'm taking the cookies values straight out of a standard logins response in the browser and pasting in.. just to narrow things down..

```
<cfhttp method="Post" url="https://www.abcdefg.com/extranet" useragent="#CGI.http_user_agent#" result="data" redirect="no">   
  <cfhttpparam type="COOKIE" name="user_credentials" value="3a52cfe8bfae077635f50ebfab4922d721d89bd3e1ada242f6af3fc138df1863dddd7ed69ca9fa3c21520738ffe9d655602c92da5938dfd696149546988b4e6e"/>
  <cfhttpparam type="COOKIE" name="_abcdefg_session" value="BAh7CSIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iMWlkLzVzUndmL1FTdnZhTXJvOTQ2bDh5QnFkbExPbzNNZmk3b3l2T1RYTjg9IhV1c2VyX2NyZWRlbnRpYWxzIgGAM2E1MmNmZThiZmFlMDc3NjM1ZjUwZWJmYWI0OTIyZDcyMWQ4OWJkM2UxYWRhMjQyZjZhZjNmYzEzOGRmMTg2M2RkZGQ3ZWQ2OWNhOWZhM2MyMTUyMDczOGZmZTlkNjU1NjAyYzkyZGE1OTM4ZGZkNjk2MTQ5NTQ2OTg4YjRlNmUiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQiJTkzZmI4N2IyODI2M2EyODZkYjNmNTFlNTdhZGRjNzg0Ihh1c2VyX2NyZWRlbnRpYWxzX2lkaQJiBQ"/>
```

I'm actually starting to wonder if it something to do with the way the request is being handled at the other end.. getting all sorts of wierd replies and nothing is quite adding up.  I have done plenty of these, but this one just seems different.. normally I have redirect="no" .. as per above, but if I take that out, then I am actually getting the entry page.. confirming I am logged in, but then when I try to access an actual url represented in that page (e.g..../extranet/reports/report.csv) I get page not found error.. I can link to it from within the page, but then if I call it with cfhttp the response is that it doesn't exist..

Sorry this is making no sense.. I am still trying to make sense of all this myself.. will repost when I start to see some trees through the forest..

Thanks again guys!

Jason

Comment: Can you provide the code of your CFHTTP requests and how you are getting the cookies out of the first and into the second?  Also, are you sure those are session cookies?

Comment: Before we can help, a few questions: 1. How are you reading the cookie values out of the response? 2. How are you setting those back into the next request? Edit your question, and add some sample coding showing how you get and then send the values, and we can try to narrow your problem down from there. Without seeing what you've tried, we'd all just be taking shots in the dark.

Comment: Could the external system potentially be checking for other cookie values that you're not passing back to them?

Comment: Now, I noticed that you referneced the cookies you receive in your description as _user_session but then in your CFHTTP request you are callign it _abcdefg_session.  I am guessign you were just changing things for obscurity, but I have to ask. You're not passing back the cookie with a different name than what you received are you?

Comment: One more question. Are you looking at the request/response cycle with something (Firebug, Fiddler, HTTPLive, WebScarab) so you can actually *see* what data is being sent from CF and what is being returned fromt he server?  THis could help greatly in determining where the problem lies. It would be nice to see the request/response data from the requests in the browser and from CF, even if you have to redact info from it. Maybe post it temporarily to pastebin or something

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with cfhttp but
this is what contain your cookies:

```
cookie 1 {
   "user_credentials" = 3a52cfe8bfae077635f50ebfab4922d721d89bd3e1ada242f6af3fc138df1863dddd7ed69ca9fa3c21520738ffe9d655602c92da5938dfd696149546988b4e6e
   "session_id" = %3c91a750c74ed3e4a3e342cf7303d65d
   [...]
}
```

et

```
cookie 2 {
   "return_to" = //extranet/properties/1326/reservations.csv,
   "session_id" = %3fe16fb29cd4970dffffa67d5ac85d4a
 }
```

Try decode from base64 to ascii to see your cookie. There is some data I could not read.